# Problemas ao tentar retornar os dados da api ser ser em uma classe

Tags: react-native

Construí uma api que me retorna as unidades que tenho cadastradas em um DB porém ao tentar retornar estas não esta repassando

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const api = {

  let: units = [],

  units: () => {
    axios.get('http://192.168.0.23/apiTeste/public/api/unidades')
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
        return response.data.data
    }).catch((error) => { 
      console.log(error.message)
    });
    return 'Falha ao tentar retornar as unidades'
  },

};

export default api;
```

O response apresenta os dados corretamente, o `response.data.data` se utilizo em um arquivo com uma classe eu consigo definir um state `units = []` e com um `setState` retornar as unidades

Porém gostaria de criar este arquivo para os retornos da api, porém como não utilizo uma classe pelo que entendi não posso utilizar o state.

Tem alguma maneria de sem o class retornar estes dados, ou guardar em uma variavel ou algo do gênero?

Ou então utilizar o `setState` aqui mesmo sem uma classe?

Ou em ultimo caso construir uma classe para ser retornado em outra classe que irá chamar a função? Ex:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import api from './units';

export default class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Units: {api.units()}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Acredito que estas seriam as formas de resolver o meu problema, mas se alguém souber de outra forma que não seja colocar a chamada da api no mesmo arquivo da classe final pode ser também.

Answer (score 1):

O que pode fazer é usar uma `Promise()`, assim voce fica sabendoq quando terminou o request e altera o seu `state` onde estiver.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const api = {

let: units = [],

units: New Promisse((resolve, reject)=>{
    axios.get('http://192.168.0.23/apiTeste/public/api/unidades')
    .then(response => {
    console.log(response);
        resolve(response.data.data)
    }).catch((error) => { 
    console.log(error.message)
    reject(error)
    });
});
};
export default api;
```

dai em algum componente qualquer por exemplo no `App` voce pode chamar `api.units` e atualizar o seu state de acardo.

```
api.units.then((result)=>{
    //result vai ser o "response.data.data" que passou para o resolve la em units
    //aqui voce pode usar o setState do component a vontade
}).catch((error)=>{
    //aqui a mesma coisa,o mesmo erro que pega no catch em units
})
```

Comment: E se no `App` eu não tiver uma classe? Ai não tenho como retornar pois não teria um `state`, ou teria alguma maneira?

Comment: ai precisa explicar melhor o que precisa, pelo que to entendendo agora voce quer atualizar o `state` do `App` a partir de uma chamada em `api.units` em algum outro lugar que nao tenha o state, tipo dentro de outro arquivo qualquer? É isso ?

Comment: Não o que eu quero é receber estes valores da api sem utilizar o state, para que possa receber os dados mesmo em um arquivo em que não esteja utilizando uma classe

Comment: ok, entao o codigo que passei funciona como esta nos comentarios `//result vai ser o "response.data.data" que passou para o resolve la em units`, os dados da api vao estar dentro do `then`, [estuda um pouco sobre promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) que vai te ajudar a entender bastante coisa da react